# Haskell parse error on input '|'

Tags: haskell, error-handling, conditional-statements

I'm getting the following error:

> parse error on input '|'

with my code:

```
makeMove :: Player -> Board -> Maybe Board
makeMove p b | hasWinner b == Nothing = getMove p rb ri
                                        where rb = gameTree p b
                                              ri = minimax p rb
                                              ros2int (i' :> ri') = i'
                                              rb2b (b':rbs') = b
                                              getMove p (r:rs) (i:is) = let bs  = map rb2b rs
                                                                            is  = map ros2int is
                                                                            idx = elemIndex (maximum' is) is
                                                                            res (Nothing) = Nothing
                                                                            res (Just x) = Just ((bs)!!x)
                                                                        in res idx
              | otherwise = Nothing
```

However I suppose this would be caused by tabs interference usually but I checked and I only used spaces so that couldn't be the problem. Could anyone help me out on this?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `where` clause should be after all guards:

```
fun a b 
  | one = ...
  | oterwise = ...
  where ....
```

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!